# Is softening a linen garment the end of the laundry process and therefore forbidden on Shabbos (Shabbos 140a)?

Tags: shabbat, maseches-shabbos, washing-clothes, makeh-befatish

Shabbos 140a. Rav Safra permits softening a laundered linen shirt. (Translation and elucidation of the Gemoro below according to Sefaria) - original is:

> מיסתמיך ואזיל רב אחא בר יוסף אכתפיה דרב נחמן בר יצחק בר אחתיה אמר ליה
>   כי מטינן לבי רב ספרא עיילינא כי מטו עייליה בעא מיניה מהו לכסכוסי
>   כיתניתא בשבתא לרכוכי כיתניתא קא מיכוין ושפיר דמי או דילמא לאולודי
>   חיורא קמיכוין ואסיר אמר ליה לרכוכי קא מיכוין ושפיר דמי
>
> The Gemara relates another incident involving Rav Aḥa bar Yosef: Rav
>   Aḥa bar Yosef was walking and leaning on the shoulder of Rav Naḥman
>   bar Yitzḥak, his sister’s son. Rav Aḥa said to him: When we arrive at
>   Rav Safra’s house, bring me in. When they arrived, Rav Naḥman brought
>   him in. Rav Aḥa then raised a dilemma before Rav Safra: What is the
>   halakha pertaining to rubbing and thereby softening a linen shirt that
>   is hard after being laundered on Shabbat? Does one intend to soften
>   the shirt, and one may well do so? Or perhaps he intends to generate
>   whiteness in the shirt, and it is prohibited? Rav Safra said to him:
>   He intends to soften, and one may well do so.

The softening renders the garment fit to wear. Why is it then not מכה בפטיש (the end of the process) of the melocho of libun?

Comment: Make bepatish is not for bone only?

Comment: @kouty What please do you mean by "bone only"?

Comment: מלאכת בונה.....

Comment: See [here](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A4%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A9) הַמַּכֶּה בַפַּטִּישׁ הוא שמה של אחת מל"ט המלאכות האסורות בשבת, מכיוון שנעשתה במהלך בניית המשכן. המלאכה המקורית הייתה כפשוטה, שימוש בפטיש לביצוע מלאכה. כאשר אומן מסיים ייצור של כלי, הוא מכה הכאות אחרונות על הכלי, כדי לעגל, או להרחיב, לקצר או לרבע את הכלי כמתוכנן[1]. **חז"ל הרחיבו את המושג לביצוע כל פעולה שמהווה סיום תהליך של הכנת דבר־מה - "גְמַר מלאכה"[2] או תיקון חפץ - "מתקן מנא" (כלי)**.

Comment: OK. I didn't know this .

Answer (score 1):

The goal of the laundry process is to maintain the cleanliness and whiteness of the garment. Softening the linen shirt is not considered an integral part of the laundry process. Thus, the softening does not finish the process of making the garment, nor does it finish the laundering process.

Regarding a Sudar, the Gemara states that there is an Isur in softening it, but this is not an act of laundering but rather a Gezeirah so that people not perform the act of laundering.

The difference between a Sudar, which is an important and prominent item of clothing worn on the head, and the linen garment is regarding how significant the softening is to wearing it. The Sudar must be softened and therefore this is more like a part of the laundering process, while the linen does not need the softening so badly and therefore it is not related to the laundering process.